# Wordpress: My Wordpress Page runs very slowly

Tags: wordpress, server, cpu-speed

My Wordpress page runs slowly, although my page isn't finished yet. If I click on any menu item then it take a lot of time until the new page has been loaded. What could be the source of its slowly running?

Have you an idea how to make the loading time more faster?

Comment: Check your plugins, deactivate all and try one by one.

Comment: Check in google page speed why the page is slow then try to solve the issues.

Comment: I will check those things. I also read it's important not to use an overloaded theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/) why the page is slow then try to solve the issues.